# How can you Embed YouTube Video using JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, video, embedding

I am working on adding cutscenes to a game mod I am writing. The game renders GUI elements using JOGL, so I have created a render event for the Player's Heads Up Display (HUD) and I want to render an overlay on this HUD which plays an embedded youtube video and then cancel the render once the youtube video stops.

```
@SubscribeEvent(priority=EventPriority.LOWEST)
public void onRender(RenderGameOverlayEvent.Post event) {
    player = mc.thePlayer;
    int height = event.resolution.getScaledHeight();
    int width = event.resolution.getScaledWidth();
                
    if(isVisible){
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        this.mc.getTextureManager().bindTexture(texture);
        drawPlayerHUD(videoCutScenePath, width, height, event);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthMask(false);
        GL11.glColor4f(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, guiOpacity);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glPopMatrix(); 
    }
}
```

When isVisible is set true - play cut scene from embeded youtube video inside the frame. I have access to the resolution of the frame (Height and Width), mouseX, mouseY, partialTick count and I have successfully displayed an image texture in png format on this frame already. I am looking to now render a video from youtube specifically. How would you accomplish this?

```
private void drawPlayerHUD(String path, int width, int height, RenderGameOverlayEvent.Post event){                                                      
    //getYouTube video so the onRender method can render it??                                                                                             
}
```

[Edit] I have tried to open the Youtube URL using the following method which also returns the status for debugging purposes and this works but it opens in a new window. I now want to merge the two and am unsure how.

```
  public static String openWebpage() {                                 
   if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
       try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=[videoID]?&autoplay=1"));
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Can't open browser for some reason";
       } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Bug Detected: The URL is invalid for some reason.";
       }
   } else {
   return "For some reason You Can't open the browser";
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't use JOGL but forget Youtube for a moment (that's just HTML text, not video data). First are you able to play any MP4 file in JOGL? If yes then your next is to get the MP4 from Youtube. The easiest way would be to save via some online downloader. Either pre-save the MP4 file in another server where you can use via direct web link or just load it from your hard drive.

Comment: **PS:** Even when MP4 works in Java, you might also have to screen grab each frame as it plays to update your `texture` variable.

Comment: **PPS**: See: [gamedev.stackexchange.com - Playing movies with OpenGL in Java](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57864/playing-movies-with-opengl-in-java).

Comment: As I understand it, I basically have to decode the video so I can update a texture frame buffer, frame by frame (have never done this before) as I render the texture using open GL.

Comment: I am having issues with streaming a texture to the GPU. I know I have to have two (or more) textures or PixelBuffer Objects that I upload the video frame data to and render respectively: -> Upload frame to texture1, Draw texture2 -> Upload to texture2, Draw texture1 ->. Repeat

Comment: Does your JOGL have a media player API? See if [this demo code](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/master/src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/demos/es2/av/MovieCube.java) works for you? If working, then you can see how they pass video as texture (_ie:_ less work than constant draw).